# TensorFlow - Jupyter Lab -Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I started using TensorFlow but I have below error after I try to install TensorFlow and keras in python3.8 on Jupyter notebook. Can you please help me, I am using Python 3.8.1 64 bit.

**I type this:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

**Output:**

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     63   try:
---> 64     from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     65   # This try catch logic is because there is no bazel equivalent for py_extension.
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-64156d691fe5> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>
     37 # go/tf-wildcard-import
     38 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
---> 39 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
     40 
     41 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     81 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     82 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 83   raise ImportError(msg)
     84 
     85 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.**
```

Comment: try pip3 install tensorflow

Comment: Are you using MacOS? This thread seems similar to your case. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43387
Or you can try to report a new issue here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#check current python version
python --version
#Create the virtual environment
conda create -n tf python=PYTHON_VERSION 
#Activate the tf environment
conda activate tf
#Install Jupyter notebook on tf Env
conda install jupyter 
#Launch jupyter notebook
jupyter notebook
#Install Tensorflow on Jupter notebook
pip install tensorflow 
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```